# matplotlib: draw two lines with inconsistent missing date

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two dataframes, say df1, and df2, defined like:

```py
df1 = {'date':['20190601','20190603','20190605','20190607','20190609'],  
       'metric':[<some metric>]  
      }  
df2 = {'date':['20190602','20190604','20190605','20190607','20190609'],  
       'metric':[<some metric>]  
      }
```

and i want to draw the two lines in the same figure, like:

```py
plt.plot(df1['date'], df1['metric'], label='df1')
plt.plot(df2['date'], df2['metric'], label = 'df2')
```

however, since there are some missing dates in both *df1* and *df2*, and the missing dates are different among them, the plotted figure becomes a mess like:
[image]

Comment: Change `df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])` and similarly for `df2`?

Comment: ... the above is to say, do not plot strings if you want to plot dates.

Comment: @QuangHoang,thanks, it helps.